# how can I determine how many times do I need to iterate in k mean cluster

Tags: matlab, iteration, k-means

I'm working on Matlab project for kmean clustering 
while I was working I found difficulties understanding the different between MaxIter and Replicates

 in my file I have 100 numbers of land size
when I run my project three times I get difference plot each time in each plot the centroid and data point location change. 

For example
First run > centroid location is x 5 , y 3 
second run > centroid location is x 3, y 2 
third run > centroid location is x 2 , y 6 
fourth run > centroid location is x 5 , y 3 
fifth  run >centroid location is x 3, y 2 
and the same pattern keep repeating 
 
so I was wondering is this normal to happen should I just take the answer/graph from the first run or the third run? 
as you can see from my code I iterate the data 3000 times which is just random number. However now I'm not sure if that correct due ti the problem that I got which is different plot in the first three run of the project 
how can I determine how many times do I need to iterate in k mean cluster

```
Array=csvread('data.csv');
  dataset = Array(:,[1:2]);


  optns = statset('MaxIter',3000);

   [idx,C] = kmeans(dataset,2,'Distance','cityblock',...
       'Options',optns);

  figure;
  plot(dataset(idx==1,1),dataset(idx==1,2),'r.','MarkerSize',20)
```

Comment: There is no "right answer" in clustering problem. You can receive different results, and it is your task to select the correct one

Comment: @AVK is there another way other than using MaxIter where I can tell it to stop iterating when there is no change ?

Answer (score 0):

kmeans.m contains the following code:

```
                % Determine which points moved
            moved = find(nidx ~= previdx);
                % Some code here .....
            if isempty(moved)
                converged = true;
                break;
            end
```

So it checks and stops if there is no change. And if `converged`is false (i.e. MaxIter is reached), it shows a warning message:

```
            if ~converged
            if reps==1
                warning(message('stats:kmeans:FailedToConverge', maxit));
            else
                warning(message('stats:kmeans:FailedToConvergeRep', maxit, rep));
            end
```